# Why does take trigger the Observable?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

I can't understand why adding .take(1) at the end of my observable, triggers the result, and if I don't it keeps pending:

```
   function generateToken(identifier){
      return new Observable<string>((observer) => {

        jwt.sign(identifier, 'devsecret', (err, token) => {
          if (err) {
            observer.error(err);
          } else if (token) {
            observer.next(token);
          }
        });
      }).pipe( take(1)); 
   }
```

Does anyone know why? Care to share the reason and whether this is a proper implementation? Mind that I'm not subscribing to this function anywhere else, but I keep piping the result.

here is where I call the method and return a response with a authorization header

```
  public login(identifier): Observable<any> {
    return generateToken(identifier).pipe(
      catchError((err: Error) => of(err)),
      map(token => {
       return {'Authorization': token}
      }));
  }
```

and last but not least this function is converted in a promise and the response is returned as an http request

```
function async userLogin(identifier) {
    return await login(identifier).toPromise();
}
```

Thanks for your time and patience

Comment: Please provide code where you pipe and subscribe

Comment: Added the extra code

Comment: it is, but the idea is to avoid using callbacks, that's the reason i wrapped it around the observable. plus the code works as expected, but I can't find anywhere why the take(1) triggers the observable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This explains your issue:

```
return await login(identifier).toPromise();
```

Promise resolves on Observable completion or rejects if it errors, so it works with `take(1)` because it takes the first Observable value and completes it.

You can also get the output if you complete it. And it looks a bit more appropriate:

```
} else if (token) {
  observer.next(token);
  observer.complete();  <---
}
```

Comment: this was indeed the answer. So if I understand correctly, the take is responsible for completing the observable at first result, which is the same as completing the observable my self

Answer (score 1):

`take(1)` makes sure the `subscriber.complete()` method is called right after the first item is emitted. BTW, this can be done directly by calling `observer.complete()` after the `observer.next()`.

[`toPromise()`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/topromise.md) will only resolve once the stream is completed, not on every emission.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.pipe( () => take(1) );
```

Or

```
.pipe( take );
```

Same behavior happens in promises. The callback wants a function not a statement.

Comment: Hi Wayne, thanks for your reply, but the function works, though I don't understand the mechanics behind it and possible consequences. Could you explain why?

Comment: I'm at a lose to explain the mechanics of the behavior. I suspect you can place a function in the queue to execute after an event but can not queue a statement. Thus the statement gets executed when it is parsed, but the function is not executed until the event. I assume in an error take(1) is executed anyway and "() => take(1)" would only execute in the no error situation. In other words the statement is always executed.

Comment: .pipe(take) should also work it resolves to a function. I didn't think of that first; I always default to the fat arrow function so I know I am passing a function when I read code that was written before lunch yesterday.